# Android Studio 2.0 Waiting for debugger

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

After updating to Android Studio 2.0 my debugger stopped working. When I try to run my app as debug I get stuck waiting for debugger. I can still run app normally.

So there are tons of post on this issue, I've tried everything I could find:

- Restart ADB
- Restart Android Studio
- Restart phone
- Restart Computer
- Switch USB port
- Update everything
- Switch develop on/off
- Tried with emulator (will also be stuck)
- Uninstal Vyzor beta (Chrome plugin that use ADB)
- Remove project and load into Android Studio again
- Updated JDK 1.7.0_71 to 1.8.0_74

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Okay so my application was using `android:process=":background"` under the application tag. So now with Android Studio 2.0 I had to click "Attach debugger to Android Process" and select the :background process.

This has not been an issue in the past.

If a single activity uses another process then the debugger will also hang at that activity until the debugger is attached to that process (attaching is done manually).